# jq: search by value from another array element

Tags: jq

I have an array of objects of various types which reference one another with UUIDs (a terraform.tfstate file). I'd like to select one value from one such object based on the appearance of a different value in another object, where the two objects are related by one of those UUIDs.

By way of example, I can do this:

```
$ jq '.modules[].resources[]
| select(.type == "openstack_compute_instance_v2" and 
         .primary.attributes.name == "jumpbox").primary.id' terraform.tfstate
"5edfe2bf-94df-49d5-8118-3e91fb52946b"
$ jq '.modules[].resources[] 
| select(.type =="openstack_compute_floatingip_associate_v2" and 
         .primary.attributes.instance_id == "5edfe2bf-94df-49d5-8118-3e91fb52946b").primary.attributes.floating_ip' terraform.tfstate
"10.120.241.21"
```

Giving me the external floating IP of the 'jumpbox' VM based on its name.

I'd like to make that all one jq call. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be easier to answer if you provided more sample data but
working backwards from your commands (with some reformatting)

```
$ jq '
      .modules[].resources[]
    | select(.type == "openstack_compute_instance_v2" and .primary.attributes.name == "jumpbox")
    | .primary.id
' terraform.tfstate
"5edfe2bf-94df-49d5-8118-3e91fb52946b"

$ jq '
      .modules[].resources[]
    | select(.type =="openstack_compute_floatingip_associate_v2" and .primary.attributes.instance_id == "5edfe2bf-94df-49d5-8118-3e91fb52946b")
    | .primary.attributes.floating_ip
' terraform.tfstate
"10.120.241.21"
```

we can infer you have data which looks like

```
{
  "modules": [
    {
      "resources": [
        {
          "type": "openstack_compute_instance_v2",
          "primary": {
            "id": "5edfe2bf-94df-49d5-8118-3e91fb52946b",
            "attributes": {
              "name": "jumpbox"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "openstack_compute_floatingip_associate_v2",
          "primary": {
            "attributes": {
              "instance_id": "5edfe2bf-94df-49d5-8118-3e91fb52946b",
              "floating_ip": "10.120.241.21"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The following filter demonstrates a solution using [functions](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#DefiningFunctions), [variables](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Variable/SymbolicBindingOperator:...as$identifier|...) and [parenthesis ()](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Parenthesis):

```
def get_primary_id($name):
    select(.type == "openstack_compute_instance_v2"
       and .primary.attributes.name == $name)
  | .primary.id
;
def get_floating_ip($id):
    select(.type =="openstack_compute_floatingip_associate_v2"
       and .primary.attributes.instance_id == $id)
  | .primary.attributes.floating_ip
;
  .modules[]
| ( .resources[] | get_primary_id("jumpbox") ) as $id
| ( .resources[] | get_floating_ip($id)      ) as $fip
| ($id, $fip)
```

if this filter is in `filter.jq` and `data.json` contains the sample data above
then

```
$ jq -M -f filter.jq data.json
```

produces the output:

```
"5edfe2bf-94df-49d5-8118-3e91fb52946b"
"10.120.241.21"
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That makes a lot of sense.